# Shaka Player: Let users choose language track

Tags: shaka

I am adapting Shaka player to our website and got stuck in the following:

- When I play my sample video in the [appspot demo](https://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/demo/demo_uncompiled.js), I see the buttons to change language and resolution:[image: This I see when playing my video in the appspot demo]
- When I follow the [tutorial](https://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/docs/api/index.html) , it does not let me choose the language: see [result](https://merucourses.com/wp-content/drm/tut02.html).

How do I configure the player to let me choose the languages?

Thank you for your help!

PS: Following later steps of the tutorial, I can change the languages, but the buttons are outside the video window, see [here](https://merucourses.com/wp-content/drm/tut02a.html). This gives me headache later on, when I proceed to offline DRM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the problem: wrong linking of css file in the html:
include a css file like this:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/filename.css">`
and not like a js script.